# Sign in email domain validation in Azure AD B2C

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I am using microsoft authentication using the steps shown in the [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-technical-profile) link.

This opens a Microsoft SSO page to sign in which works as expected. This allows us to sign in through different microsoft hosted emails such as `your-email@hotmail.com`, `your-email@outlook.com` etc. What I want to do now is to add a validation to make the email domain bound for example only allow `@outlook.com` users to sign in. How can we do this using custom policy?

We tried adding following code suggested in [this](https://www.wintellect.com/hello-world-and-then-some-with-azure-active-directory-b2c-custom-policies-part-4-hello-but-only-if-you-have-an-access-code/) link:

```
<ClaimsTransformation Id="GetDomainFromEmail" TransformationMethod="ParseDomain">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" TransformationClaimType="emailAddress" />
  </InputClaims>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domain" TransformationClaimType="domain" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>

<ClaimsTransformation Id="LookupDomain" TransformationMethod="LookupValue">
  <InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domain" TransformationClaimType="inputParameterId" />
  </InputClaims>
  <InputParameters>
    <InputParameter Id="wintellect.com" DataType="string" Value="valid" />
    <InputParameter Id="microsoft.com" DataType="string" Value="valid" />
    <InputParameter Id="test.com" DataType="string" Value="valid" />
    <InputParameter Id="errorOnFailedLookup" DataType="boolean" Value="true" />
  </InputParameters>
  <OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="domainStatus" TransformationClaimType="outputClaim" />
  </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

But could not upload this policy and got this error:

```
Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy "B2C_1A_SIGNUP_SIGNIN" of tenant "<yor-tenant-id>.onmicrosoft.com".Invalid technical profile with id "Common-AAD" only the protocol handler ""Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"" can have a ValidationTechnicalProfile.Invalid technical profile with id "Common-AAD" only the protocol handler ""Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"" can have a ValidationTechnicalProfile.
```

Any help on how to verify domain in Microsoft SSO would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

**EDIT**:
The technical profile is as follows:

```
 <TechnicalProfile Id="Common-AAD">
          <DisplayName>Microsoft Account or Microsoft-Connected Account</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
          <OutputTokenFormat>JWT</OutputTokenFormat>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="authorization_endpoint">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize</Item>
            <Item Key="client_id">my-client-id</Item>
            <Item Key="DiscoverMetadataByTokenIssuer">true</Item>
            <Item Key="HttpBinding">POST</Item>
            <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">my-id</Item>
            <Item Key="response_types">id_token</Item>
            <Item Key="scope">openid profile email offline_access</Item>
            <Item Key="UsePolicyInRedirectUri">false</Item>
            <Item Key="ValidTokenIssuerPrefixes">https://login.microsoftonline.com/,https://sts.windows.net/</Item>
            <Item Key="METADATA">https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/.well-known/openid-configuration</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <!-- Make sure to update the reference ID of the client secret below you just created (B2C_1A_AADAppSecret) -->
            <Key Id="client_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_AppSecret" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" PartnerClaimType="iss" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surName" PartnerClaimType="family_name" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="preferred_username" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="otherMails" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaimsTransformations>
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" />
            <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </OutputClaimsTransformations>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-SocialLogin" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

Comment: The error is with `Common-AAD`, can you paste that Technical Profile/s in the question? Also paste anything that references `GetDomainFromEmail` and `LookupDomain`

Comment: @JasSuri Is there a way in which I can use Microsoft SSO but make it domain bound?

Comment: @JasSuri I have also added the technical profile for which we want the email to be domain bound.

Comment: Somewhere in your files you have a TP `Common-AAD` with a ValidationTechnicalProfile defined. You may have `Common-AAD` defined in multiple files, double check. You cannot put a ValidationTechnicalProfile  against a claimsExchange with another IdP, such as OIDC in this case.

Comment: @JasSuri the TP I shared with you does not cause an issue. I want to make Microsoft SSO email domain bound. Do you know a way to do so?

Comment: You can run these claims transforms as part of a claim transform technical profile. After the MS Account orchestration step, invoke an orchestration step to call your claims transforms technical profile. Use the claims transforms to set a boolean on whether the user can/cant continue. Then add an orchestration step which has a precondition based on this boolean. This step should execute a self asserted step with continue button disabled, which prevents an unknown domain from continuing to get a token.